# Displaying z-indexed divs over another div in same container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a container div which contains a table. I am adding divs dynamically to container div using jQuery. I want to position the created divs over the table but unable to do so. The child divs appear below the table. Here is my code

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="tbl">
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </table>    
</div>    
<button id="btnAdd" type="button">Add</button>
```

CSS:

```
.container
{
  position:relative;
  background-color:#d0d0d0;
  width:90%;
  height:50px;
}
.innerdiv
{
  z-index:2;
  background-color: #D57657;
  float:left;    
}
.tbl
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.tbl td
{
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $("#btnAdd").click(function(){
    $(".container").append("<div class='innerdiv'>I am new</div>");
  });
});
```

and here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZedBee/ABZ8s/)

Comment: Not the answer but `position:releative;` should be `position:relative;` and `widht:90%;` should be `width:90%;`

Answer (score 0):

```
.container{
    position:releative;
    background-color:#d0d0d0;
    widht:90%;
    height:50px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: sure.. thanks.. thats what happens at the end of the day when one spends whole day just figuring out how to lay a div over another.